# Tidymodels error with fit. Error: `x` and `y` must have same types and lengths

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

I have the following code:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)

rps <- tribble( ~estado,   ~comp_move,  ~move,
                "gana",    "piedra",    "papel", 
                "pierde",  "papel",     "piedra",
                "pierde",  "papel",     "piedra",
                "gana",    "tijeras",   "piedra",
                "gana",    "piedra",    "papel",  
                "pierde",  "tijeras",   "papel",  
                "gana",    "papel",     "tijeras",
                "gana",    "piedra",    "papel",  
                "pierde",  "papel",     "piedra", 
                "gana",    "tijeras",   "piedra",
                "empate",  "piedra",    "piedra", 
                "pierde",  "papel",     "piedra", 
                "empate",  "papel",     "papel",  
                "gana",    "tijeras",   "piedra")

rps <- rps %>% mutate_if(is.character,factor)
rps.split  <- initial_split(rps, prop = 0.75)
rps.rec    <- recipe(estado ~ comp_move + move, rps) %>% 
                   step_dummy(all_nominal(),-all_outcomes())
rps.rec.prep <- rps.rec %>% prep()

base.model <- rand_forest() %>%
                set_engine("ranger") %>%             
                set_mode("classification")

last_fit(base.model, rps.rec, rps.split)
```

I have also tried to use workflows

```
wfl <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(rps.rec) %>%
  add_model(base.model)
last_fit(wfl, split = rps.split)
```

When using `last_fit()` I get the following error:

```
`Error: `x` and `y` must have same types and lengths`
```

I have used kknn, decision_tree, random_forest and xgboost, all getting same erros. I am also getting the same error even when tuning parameters with `tune_grid()`.

The thing is that when I use `fit()` function everything works fine. I know it is because I am using the model wrong but, why am I getting that error? I am new to tidymodel package.

Thanks in advance.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.15.5
```

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example so I can run it and find the source of the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Reinstalled new RStudio version and finally works.

Comment: Oh good; I was just trying to figure out why I could not reproduce this.

Comment: Interestingly I've had _exactly_ this error today, so I'm wondering if it's related to a version of a package. I'm using R in docker via `Rscript` so nothing to do with RStudio. I don't have a reproducible example, but if I get to the bottom of it I'll post here.

Comment: Yes it was a package version issue. I was using the latest rocker/verse:4.0.0, but this is actually not tied to an MRAN date, therefore new package installs I did on top (e.g. tidymodels) were versions released later than packages included in rocker/verse (e.g. dplyr). Something to keep in mind for the future.